# Javascript not starting on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've looked several places for an answer, but even though I've found people with similar problems, the solutions they got did not help me sadly.

I have a JS in my header, that wont load when the page loads. The body is running an onload for the function ShowTime but that doesn't work either, same for the document.ready. Im slowly getting frustrated, so I came here for help. I've tested it in jsfiddle where it works just fine, just not in my browser.

The script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">   
    function ShowTime() 
        {
            var now = new Date();
            var hrs = 15-now.getHours();
            var mins = 60-now.getMinutes();
            var secs = 60-now.getSeconds();
            timeLeft = "" +hrs+' hours '+mins+' minutes '+secs+' seconds';
            $("#countdown").html(timeLeft);
        }

        var countdown;
        function StopTime() 
        {
            clearInterval(countdown);   
        }

        ShowTime();
        var countdown = setInterval(ShowTime ,1000);
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use a seperate `<script>` tag for you code. So 2 in total, one to load jQuery and one for your written code.

Comment: Wrap your code on <script> $(document).ready(function(){ /*put all code here */ }) </script> and script tag is missing .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's working just you close `<script>` wrong

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 function ShowTime() 
    {
        var now = new Date();
        var hrs = 15-now.getHours();
        var mins = 60-now.getMinutes();
        var secs = 60-now.getSeconds();
        timeLeft = "" +hrs+' hours '+mins+' minutes '+secs+' seconds';
        $("#countdown").html(timeLeft);
    }

    var countdown;
    function StopTime() 
    {
        clearInterval(countdown);   
    }

    ShowTime();
    var countdown = setInterval(ShowTime ,1000);
});
</script>
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d0abk8cb/)

Comment: That did it, thanks! Never had a problem like that before :)

Comment: @H4rdstyler : please accept the answer if you have found this usefull

Comment: I will once I can, 7 minutes :)

Comment: Please check this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780890/jquery-function-inside-document-ready-function. Declaring functions in document.ready is also a matter of scope.