# Show/Hide part of the page based on dropdown choice in MVC 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdown in MVC5 "view" by changing the dropdown part of the page is going to show and hide. I like to call this function in page load but is not working properly it shows all the text boxes when page loads as I don't know how to send "e" to the page load and when I change the drop down it gave me this error:

```
  Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'toggleDIvDisplay' is undefined
```

This is my code:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(

function toggleDIvDisplay(e) {

    if (e == 1) {
        $('#divAppName').hide();
        $('#divSSN').hide();
        $('#divRemref').hide();

    }

    if (e == 2) {
        $('#divAppName').show();
        $('#divSSN').hide();
        $('#divRemref').hide();

    }

    if (e == 3) {
        $('#divSSN').show();
        $('#divAppName').hide();
        $('#divRemref').hide();
    }


    if (e == 4) {
        $('#divRemref').show();
        $('#divSSN').hide();
        $('#divAppName').hide();

    }
```

and this is dropdown:

```
Search By: @Html.DropDownList("ddl", (SelectList)ViewBag.DropDownValues, new   { @onchange = "toggleDIvDisplay(this.value)" })
```

thanks everyone for the answer.
Solution is to add this lines:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    toggleDIvDisplay(1);
});
```

Comment: Try something like `$(document).ready(function () { toggleDIvDisplay(whateveryouwantEtobe);});` if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Instead of just saying `it is not working properly`, why can't you say the error you got ?

Comment: I am assuming `e` is the value of your `dropdown` and you need to `toggle` div's based on the dropdown value. you can try something like this `$('#myDropDownID').on('change', function(){ if($(this).val() == 1){ // your code here and other conditions} });`

Comment: please check my answer @Alma. let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I dont think you should create the function in document.ready,
[From this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780890/jquery-function-inside-document-ready-function)

defining it outside the document.ready will make it accessible to your jS after your page has loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Right after you define the function in `$(document).ready()`, just call it:

```
toggleDIvDisplay(1);
```

The above assumes you want your page-load behavior to be when `e` is set to `1`.

```
$(document).ready(
    function toggleDIvDisplay(e) {
        // ... your implementation, removed for brevity
    }

    toggleDIvDisplay(1);
);
```

Comment: it gave methis error when I try to change the dropdown  -  error: 'toggleDIvDisplay' is undefined

Answer (score 0):

assuming `ddl` is the `id` of your dropdown, you can try this.

***EDIT:*** simplified your conditions.

```
$(function() {
    $('#ddl').on('change', function() {
        var value = $(this).val();

        $('#divAppName, #divSSN, #divRemref').hide();

        if (value == 2) {
            $('#divAppName').show();
        }       
        else if (value == 3) {
            $('#divSSN').show();
        }       
        else if (value == 4) {
            $('#divRemref').show();
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write your function in a way that it gets the value of the dropdown inside the function itself:

```
function setDivVisibility() {
    var e = $('#ddl').val();

    if (e == 1) {
        // Show/Hide elements
    } else if (e == 2) {
        // Show/Hide elements
    }
    // and so on...
}
```

Then call the function for the first time on document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setModeVisibility();
});
```

**Bonus:** For unobtrusive JavaScript, put this in the document ready as well so you don't need to the `onchange` behavior mixed in with the html.

```
$('#ddl').change(function () {
    setModeVisibility();
});
```