# Why are my javascript or jquery functions not found when wrapped in $document.ready function () or $function()

Tags: javascript

in javascript when I wrap my functions (below) in either $(Document).ready(Function(){ ... }) or $function(){ ... } I receive errors that the my function AddContact or EditContact is not found.
I am using MVC and this was what I thought would a remedy my issue with javascript being not found after HttpPost, so if someone could explain how to wrap these inside ot $.ready(function() maybe I could resolve both issues.

```
<script>
       var AddContact = function (id) {

            var url = "../Dataset/AddContact/" + id
            $("#myModalBody").load(url, function () {
                $("#myModal").modal("show");
            })


        };

        var EditContact = function (id) {

            var url = "../Dataset/EditContact/" + id
            $("#myModalBody").load(url, function () {
                $("#myModal").modal("show");
            })


        };
</script>
```

Comment: Because the functions will not be in global scope. They will be scoped to the document.ready function.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+jquery+function+inside+document.ready+not+found) of [jQuery - function inside $(document).ready function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6780890/4642212) or [Javascript function inside document.ready](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18504253/4642212).